# How to get default database name using Transact-SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, drop-database, default-database

My initial concern was to `DROP DATABASE MyDB`  when a certain condition is met but I get this error:

> Database 'MyDB' is still in use

So, the answer I found was to do

```
USE master 
DROP DATABASE MyDB
```

It works, but for my case there is no guarantee whether `master` will be the default database on the server or not.

I would like to know how do I get the default database name for that particular server so that I can write something like

```
USE Default_DB 
DROP DATABASE MyDB
```

Comment: `master` will always be there for any SQL Server instance - it's one of the four pre-defined, pre-created and **must have** databases on any SQL Server instance. I think doing a `USE master` is always safe.

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

The default database is set per login, not for the server. If not specified when creating a login, it defaults to **'`master`'**.

You change it like this:

```
ALTER LOGIN [user_name] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [default_database]
```

Ref: [CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

To answer your actual question, you should always move to 'master' to delete a database:

```
USE master
GO

DROP DATABASE MyDB
GO
```